# Node.JS: Removing unnecessary MongoDB files

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written a Node.JS application that I will have to ship soon, in the form of an RPM (RedHat Package Manager), with everything included (Node, CSS, JS, MongoDB, Node modules, etc.) The total application weights about 60MB compressed, of which about 50MB comes from MongoDB. I would like to reduce the size of the final shipment.

Now, as far as I'm concerned, my Node.JS application only explicitly executes `mongod`. Looking at the `mongodb-linux-i686-2.2.2/bin` directory I see about a dozen executables, most of which weight 10.3MB (that's a little curious that so many weight 10.3MB), such as `bsondump`, `mongodump`, `mongoexport`, `mongofiles`, `mongoimport`, etc.

Which MongoDB executables are being run under the hood in my "standard" (single database, no sharding, nothing fancy) Node.JS application? Which can I remove for the final shipment?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off depending on the MongoDB RPM?

Comment: It's a requirement that our RPM fits everything.

Comment: The reason that so many of the mongodb binaries are large is that the executables shipped by mongodb are statically linked. Also, please note that as mentioned by Alister Bulman below, mongodb is AGPL licensed so there are consequences for your code for bundling it. You should contact 10gen to ensure that what you are attempting to do does not violate the license terms. 10gen does offer commercial licenses which may be an option for you if the AGPL path is not workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only mongod would be required in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be legal to create your own distribution of the MongoDB server. See http://www.mongodb.org/about/licensing/ and I would also ask http://www.10gen.com directly for clarification.